# Can we have some statistics on suggested edit reviews?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, statistics

There are two (possibly three) ways to review suggested edits:

1. via the [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)
2. by visiting a Q&A page where the edit was made, and clicking on the `edit (1)` link underneath a post
3. authors of a post get an inbox notification when a suggested edit is made; however, clicking that link redirects you to the review item itself, inside the review queues (1.)

Is there *anything* known about the number of reviews made via 1. and 2.? Mainly because I'm curious, but it could also help in determining ways to improve reviewing. As they say in the Netherlands, *meten is weten* (to measure is to know; in Dutch it rhymes nicely). It's likely that it's not directly stored in the database, but perhaps it can combined with page views?

I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1347021/of-edits-reviewed-by-post-owners) to check how many edits were reviewed by post owners (about 16% here, on Stack Overflow and Mathematics; other sites like Super User and Ask Different have single-digit percentages). Interesting, but not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: IIRC, WRT #3 - won't you get this notification even if you can't normally access the review queues (e.g., review-baned, don't have enough reputation)

Comment: @Mureinik users can always review edits made on their own post, same way they can comment. This surely bypass any reputation limitation for review, and possibly even review banned users can still review edits made on their own post.

Comment: @Mureinik it doesn't make much sense to restrict this for authors of a post. The post owner can always make an edit without needing to have it approved. It's this mechanism that allows them to have the final say on suggested edits for their post. They can even overrule a reached consensus - they can approve a rejected one or reject an approved one unilaterally.